# Maximum Number of simultaneous connections from any machine

Tags: http, tcp, concurrency, load-testing

We are trying to do Load test on our servers, for this we are currently using JMeter.
However we have decided to use golang's concurrency model to create simultaneous http requests to the server and perform the load test.

Is there any limitations on how many http requests or tcp connections a machine can open/send to any other machine, is there any way to find this number?

Edit----
We need this number since this will help us identify how many http request can be sent simultaneously to the server

Thanks

Comment: The question is about the client (outgoing connections), not the server. I expect the first limit to be running out of local ports.

Comment: @Flimzy No. The question is about 'number of simultaneous connections *from* any machine', 'how many HTTP requests or TCP connections a machine can open/send *to* any other machine', etc. Not one word in it about how many connections a server can handle.

Comment: @Flimzy Relevant how? If it's of the order of a million, it's several orders of magnitude bigger than the port limit.

Comment: @Flimzy The link you posted shows that it isn't, and the question is still about HTTP requests and connections. Not goroutines. Your logic escapes me.

Comment: @Flimzy The purpose of tagging this with "Go" was since the test tool we have written is implemented in Go, if this has caused any confusion , I will try to remove it. No where in the question I have spoken about any limitations of Go routines

Comment: @Pharaoh: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any limitations on how many http requests or tcp connections a machine can open/send to any other machine, is there any way to find this number?

Yes. When connecting to a single target, you are limited by the number of outbound ports, which is 65535. In practice somewhat less, as not all ports are available for use as outbound ports.

> We need this number since this will help us identify how many http request can be sent simultaneously to the server

From any one machine. It has nothing to do with the maximum number of connections from different machines.

Comment: That's the limit per IP. It's not unheard of to bind multiple virtual interfaces to get as many ports as you need, so it still really just comes down to available resources.